# How to edit only one list in a split list view?

Tags: interaction-design, iphone, ios

I'm helping out developing an iPhone app that enables access to a lot of list items of data.

On the start screen, the user can dig into the list items through either predefined category shortcuts or user-defined shortcuts. The latter shortcuts are created by using the predefined category shortcuts to navigate to the requested list/item and then tapping a 'create shortcut' button.

However, I'm in doubt how to design the interaction for editing such split lists; that is deleting, re-arranging and renaming user-defined shortcuts on the start screen (only user-defined shortcuts can be edited).

My draft looks like this:

[image: iPhone interaction design draft]

- **What are your comments on this design? Does is comply with iOS
  standards? Is it even implementable? Can you think of a better design?**

Answer (score 3):

In your current illustration, i might move the cancel / save buttons below the text field.

You could have editable text fields on your edit page while in edit mode. So user created short cut labels are editable in place.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I did actually consider allowing inline renaming; I'm not sure it complies with best practices, though.
Regarding the placement of the Cancel/Save buttons, you're right in terms of layout flow. However, I'm mimicking the navigation bar layout, with the label in the middle and the action buttons on each side and the actionable view/item below.

Comment: If you don't do inline (I think you should), I would consider using a UIAlertView with a text field, ala: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_QLwms0mVa4w/Sabn1cXUeuI/AAAAAAAAAGY/HWNYS7OU6Gw/s400/iPhone+SimulatorScreenSnapz004.jpg Also, remember to allocate room for the keyboard.

Comment: @Stuart - you're right about making room for the keyboard - I almost forgot... I agree, that inline editing would be the coolest. I haven't found a source that confirms that this is indeed feasible in terms of implementation (when you already have the edit mode with delete and re-arrange activated), though. With regards to the UIAlertView, I'm not so sure. In terms of "fittsian" finger travel distance from the keyboard, my proposal is preferable, I believe.